# Vertical centering of figure in landscape environment

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, landscape

I am using the pdflscape package to insert landscape pages in my document. On one of these I would like to have a figure that is **vertically** centered on the page, but I can't find how to do it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
A portrait mode page...

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{VUB_logo.pdf}}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

Another portrait mode page...
\end{document}
```

This results in something like this (only landscape page shown):
[image: Landscape page with figure not vertically centered]

While what I would like is this:
[image: Landscape page with figure vertically centered]
(note the vertical centering)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would do it using a `\parbox` which has the maximum height (i.e. `\textwidth` because of the rotation) and contains some `\vfill` macros before and after the content to push it into the middle. Note that in such cases you shouldn't use the `figure` floating environment but add the captions using `\captionof{figure}` (`capt-of` or `caption` package). The float only interferes here. Because the content has already the maximum width you don't need to center it horizontally. This can however be done using the `[c]` option of the `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}
A portrait mode page...

\begin{landscape}
\parbox[c][\textwidth][s]{\linewidth}{%
\vfill
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax]{VUB_logo.pdf}}
\captionof{figure}{Some caption}
\vfill
}
\end{landscape}

Another portrait mode page...
\end{document}
```

I also compensated for the `\fbox` dimension to not generate an overfull box.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I will try this out now. One remark though, what I forgot the mention was that I only included the fbox in my example to more clearly mark the extent of the figure. So what would your solution look like without the fbox?

Comment: @Matthias: Then it is even simpler: write the one line as `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{VUB_logo.pdf}}%`

Comment: `\centering\vspace*{\fill}` immediately after `\begin{landscape}` and `\vfill` before `\end{landscape}` will not require the `\parbox` (and even the `\noindent` you forgot to add before the `\parbox`).

Comment: @egrep: Yours works too but the result is slightly different: the vertical centering is based on the figure alone, not on the figure + its caption (may because both are not wrapped together in a float environment?). But the result looks nice anyway. So thanks!

Comment: @Matthias you can try to add the space of caption using

Comment: `\setbox0=\vbox{\captionof*{table}{tablecaption}}%
     \vspace{\dimexpr\ht0/2\relax}`

Comment: just after `\centering\vspace*{\fill}`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried resetting the length parameters `\@fptop` and `\@fpbot` to their default value of `0pt plus 1fil`? These parameters govern the amount of "fil" above and below a float on a float-only page. It may be that one of the packages you use has reset the `@fptop` parameter to something like `0pt`. :-( You'd put the following commands in your document's preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
```

By the way, you may also want to look into using the `rotating` package and its commands `\begin{sidewaysfigure}` ... `\end{sidewaysfigure}`. Not only would you have a couple fewer commands to type each time you need to create a landscape-oriented float :-), you'd also get to benefit from the `rotating` package's habit of vertically centering the contents of the float on the page. The following MWE demonstrates its use. Happy TeXing!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{VUB_logo.pdf}
\caption{A sideways figure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I'm afraid your first solution does not work for me (the figure is not vertically centered), I tried it with and with out a figure environment. You second solution works but the pdf page is not put in landscape mode, with pdflscape's `landscape` environment it is. So I'm sticking with the solution provided above.

Comment: I am using a preamble diployed by my university and they set `\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}`. I don't know why this is needed? It screwed totally my `sidewaysfigure` environment positioning of my figure. Could you explain, why this `@fptop` is probably changed?

Comment: I could not find this answer with the keywords positioning and sidewaysfigure nor in other combination. Only after I identified my problem I was able to find it in combination with the `\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}` string. Maybe we should answer this problem as a separately question!