# Using KOMAoptions to produce landscape output produces empty page

Tags: floats, pdftex, koma-script, landscape

I am writing my thesis and received a template for inserting landscape graphics on a typical paper when using `pdflatex` (which I am). It looks like this:

```
\newpage
\KOMAoptions{pagesize,paper=landscape,DIV=20} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
...
\end{figure}
\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,paper=portrait,DIV=10}
```

If I typeset the template it looks perfect, but if I do it on my own thesis, the following happens: I get an empty page (this is also where `thispagestyle` is applied) and one with my graphic (which now has a header again). Commenting out `newpage` (both) did not change *anything*! And moving `thispagestyle` around (below figure, in figure block) did not change *anything* as well.

So basically whatever I change its like `pdflatex` ignores all everything and just does what it wants. Removing `thispagestyle` just adds header to the empty page again.

So my goal: One page with a landscape image. But what I get: One empty page (even no header) and one page with image & header (both are in landscape).

Why is that happening and why is latex ignoring all my settings (if it doesn't matter if I write two `newpage` why bother adding them?

Since I am not a latex guru, please tell me if you need additional information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm surprised that `\KOMAoptions` works in the document; I'd expect it to work only in the preamble. You should not expect to be able to switch page sizes in the document that way.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Yeah it does work, but are warning is emitted that this is a "dirty hack", but since this came from a template, I thought it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative approaches:

- Package `pdflscape` (or `lscape`):

  ```
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  ...
  \clearpage
  \begin{landscape}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    ...
  \end{landscape}
  ```

  Example: [Vertical centering of figure in landscape environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28600/16967)
- Environment `sidewaystable` of package `rotating`.

Empty page: a complete MWE with warnings/errors from the `.log` file would be useful.